# Crystal Reports : Keeping different sections together

Tags: crystal-reports

Is it possible to keep different Crystal Reports Sections together ?
I have the following setup :

```
Group
Details
```

What I want is for the Group to always appear with its details on the same page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do the following:

- Right-click the Group Header section, and select "Change Group"
- At the bottom, select "Keep Group Together" and "Repeat Group Header On Each Page"

Your Group Header should now repeat on each page, and they should all be grouped together on the same page (so you shouldn't have a group header at the bottom of the page, and then the details start on the next page).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your answer @LittleBobbyTables

However for Crystal Reports 10 and above, I found a little bit different option

- Right-click the Group Header section, and select **"Group Expert"**
- Click **Options..**
- Select **Options** tab
- Check **"Keep Group Together"** check box
- Check **"Repeat Group Header On Each Page"** check box (*If you want to repeat Group Header on every page*)